# Telegram bot to send auto message every n hours with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am quite new in building bots so I created a very simple Telegram bot and it works great but can't figure out how to make the bot send messages every n minutes or n hours when  /start_auto command is initiated.

I made a workaround with while loop but it looks stupid and during the loop users won't be able to interact with the bot about other topics.

I want users to be able to start and stop this scheduled task by commands such as /start_auto and /stop_auto.

I know there are many other answered questions related to this topic but none of them seem to be working with my code.

```
import logging
import os
import time

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))


def start(update, context):
    """Sends a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')


def help(update, context):
    """Sends a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')


def start_auto(update, context):
    """Sends a message when the command /start_auto is issued."""
    n = 0
    while n < 12:
        time.sleep(3600)
        update.message.reply_text('Auto message!')
        n += 1


def error(update, context):
    """Logs Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)


def main():
    TOKEN = 'TOKEN_GOES_HERE'
    APP_NAME = 'https://my-tele-test.herokuapp.com/' 

    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start_auto", start_auto))

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0", port=PORT, url_path=TOKEN, webhook_url=APP_NAME + TOKEN)
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: check this https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

will post a solution which I found:

```
def callback_auto_message(context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id='12345678', text='Automatic message!')


def start_auto_messaging(update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    context.job_queue.run_repeating(callback_auto_message, 10, context=chat_id, name=str(chat_id))
    # context.job_queue.run_once(callback_auto_message, 3600, context=chat_id)
    # context.job_queue.run_daily(callback_auto_message, time=datetime.time(hour=9, minute=22), days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), context=chat_id)


def stop_notify(update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Stopping automatic messages!')
    job = context.job_queue.get_jobs_by_name(str(chat_id))
    job[0].schedule_removal()
```

And in the main function I created a commands:

```
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("auto", start_auto_messaging))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("stop", stop_notify))
```

Answer (score 6):

`python-telegram-bot` has a built-in feature for scheduling tasks, called `JobQueue`. Please have a look at [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) for versions <20 or [the documentation](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html) for later versions for more info.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is simple here, you only need the time library and one while loop to send an auto-message. time.sleep(30)) shows how often messages are sent in seconds.

```
import telebot
from telebot import custom_filters
import time


bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN FOR BOT")



# Chat id can be private or supergroups.
@bot.message_handler(chat_id=[123456789], commands=['start']) # chat_id checks id corresponds to your list or not.
def admin_reply(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "You are allowed to use this command.")
    while(True):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Allowed to receive an auto-message every 30 seconds.", time.sleep(30))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def not_admin(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "You are not allowed to use this command")
    while(True):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Allowed to receive an auto-message every minute.", time.sleep(60))

# Do not forget to register
bot.add_custom_filter(custom_filters.ChatFilter())
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use pyrogram. It has made everything easier.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters 
import time

app = Client('my_account',          #Update this line with
               api_id=API_ID,       #your API_ID
               api_hash=API_HASH,   #your API_HASH
               bot_token=BOT_TOKEN) #your BOT_TOKEN

def main():
    while(True):
        app.send_message(chat_id=123456789, text="This message is sent every 5 mins")
        time.sleep(5000) app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks but as I said I don't want a while loop. I need some kind of a scheduler where the bot will send the message every n hours or every day at 10:00:00 o'clock, something like that.

Comment: Why do u don't wanna use WHILE loop. Tell me what problem you are facing and I will help you out

Comment: During the loop users won't be able to interact with the bot about other topics, for example sending other commands such as /help etc.

Comment: Okay I have an Idea. Create another Bot. Make that bot to message the group or the first bot itself every 5 mins or something using loop and on that message event make the first Bot do the work.

Comment: This seem way too complex, I already posted an answer above which is simple and useful. Thanks anyway.